# How to create a batch update with jOOQ using dynamic query parameters

Tags: jooq

I'm in Spring Boot using Groovy, my `jooq` instance is basically the same as `create` in the documentation. Assume all undefined things are what they should be...

We've done stuff like this in the past:

```
int bulkUpdate(List<Thing> things) {
    UpdateSetMoreStep update = jooq.update(TABLE)

    things.each { Thing thing ->
        update.set(getField(thing.prop1), thing.value)
    }

    return update.where(CONDITION).execute()
}
```

This has worked fine.

What I'm looking for is how to do this in a batch. Meaning, I've potentially got a `List<Thing>` with 100 items, I need to dynamically define 100 `update` instances and I want to execute them all at once (one database transaction, all or nothing).

Is the only option to do something like this?

```
int bulkUpdate(List<Thing> things) {
    UpdateSetMoreStep update = jooq.update(TABLE)

    def updates = things.collect { Thing thing ->
        return update.set(getField(thing.prop1), thing.value)
    }

    return jooq.batch(updates).execute().sum()
}
```

My actual use-case here is much more complex, requiring a sub-select and (I think) multiple updates per iteration. So I'm just trying to understand if I'm missing something in the documentation/API or if this is the best/only way to accomplish this.

To clarify a bit about what I'm looking for, we often do something like this, which is quite a nice way to get a lot done in a loop:

```
int bulkInsert(List<Thing> things) {
    InsertValuesStep<N> insertStep = jooq.insertInto(TABLE).columns(col1, col2)

    things.each {
        insertStep = insertStep.values(it.prop1, it.prop2)
    }

    return insertStep.execute()
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar with a batch? Like this:

```
int bulkUpdate(List<Thing> things) {
    def batch = jooq.batch()
    UpdateSetMoreStep update = jooq.update(TABLE)

    things.each { Thing thing ->
        batch += update.set(getField(thing.prop1), thing.value)
    }

    batch.execute().sum()
}
```

Again, nothing wrong with `jooq.batch(updates).execute()`, but I want to know if that's the only way or if there's something in the API that's slightly more convenient, like my last example.

Finally, I'm stuck on whatever version of jOOQ rolls out with `spring-boot-starter-jooq:2.6.9`, which I think is 3.12. I'm certainly open to hearing about options available in newer versions, but ideally, we focus on a solution I can implement "today."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A possibly more convenient approach is to use [jOOQ's batched connection](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batched-connection/), which transparently batches stuff behind the scenes, delaying statements until any batch flush condition is triggered, including:

- The statement's SQL changes
- The batch size is reached
- The transaction commits
- The batched connection is closed

> Finally, I'm stuck on whatever version of jOOQ rolls out with spring-boot-starter-jooq:2.6.9, which I think is 3.12

That is quite the arbitrary limitation. You can upgrade jOOQ independently of Spring Boot. But if that's not possible, you can also just copy the `BatchedConnection` from the latest jOOQ versions and use only that.

Comment: I appreciate the response, Lukas. However, this is happening in the middle of a rather complex set of operations and I need to directly control when the batch is executed. And yes, it is an arbitrary limitation; we're "very careful" about keeping things lock-step so nothing breaks unexpectedly. I have dreams of "someday."

Comment: @randy: I mean, I just wanted to give you one alternative since that's what you asked for, but I don't really understand your question. Your approach worked, and it gives you the fine grained control you wanted. So, what exactly were you expecting? `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are quite different statements, so naturally, they don't work exactly the same way. I don't really see why the `UPDATE` case is bothering you, but not the `INSERT` case...

Comment: I think it's just because I can interact directly with the `insert` instance to achieve a "bulk insert." Whereas the `update` instance doesn't work like that; it requires a completely separate operation. In a way, it feels like the API is missing something, or is inconsistent in that regard. Don't get me wrong, I love jOOQ and appreciate everything you do. And I understand that, fundamentally, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are different in SQL. There's certainly nothing wrong with the collect-to-batch approach, I just thought there might be something more similar to the insert approach.

Comment: @randy: Well, there's `MERGE`, which you can use as a more sophisticated `UPDATE`, if you only use the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause, or use `UPDATE .. FROM`, if your RDBMS supports it (and/or jOOQ can emulate it)